# split an array into two equal sized arrays

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am working on a program in eclipse to split an array into two arrays of equal size. My program compiles, but when I run it I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10000     at mergeArrays.main(mergeArrays.java:28)

If you have any suggestions as to why I am getting this error it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class mergeArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.print("Enter an upper limit: ");
        //int lim = input.nextInt();
        int lim = 10000;
        int halfLim;
        halfLim = lim / 2;
        //int data[];
        //data = new int[lim];

        double[] data = new double[lim];
        for (int i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
            data[i] = Math.random();
        }

        double[] a = new double[halfLim];

        for (int i = 0; i < halfLim; i++) {
            a[i] = data[i];
        }

        double[] b = new double[halfLim];
        for (int i = halfLim; i < lim; i++) {
            b[i] = data[i];
        }

        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @davidxxx:  That's not the issue there.  `Math.random()` returns `double`, and it's not being used (like, at all) to index into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last iterator is wrong

use this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lim ; ++i) {
   b[i] = data[i+halfLim];
}
```

instead of :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < halfLim ; ++i) {
   b[i] = data[i+halfLim];
}
```

A more optimal way is to combine both loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < halfLim ; ++i) {
   a[i] = data[i];
   b[i] = data[i+halfLim];
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, your third and final form is more correct than your first form.

Answer (score 0):

Since `lim` > `halfLim` you access out of bound elements

```
double[] b = new double[halfLim]; // your promise of halfLim
for(int i = halfLim ; i < lim ; ++i) {
   b[i] = data[i+halfLim]; // did you betray?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the below loop:

```
 for(int i = halfLim ; i < lim ; ++i) {
    b[i] = data[i+halfLim];
 }
```

It should be `data[i]` and not `data[i+halfLim]`. This is because you have already initialized the variable `i` to the value of `halfLim`, so you just start the 2nd half from this value till `< lim`.

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues to tackle.

First, `b[i]` is not going to index into anything successfully.  `b` is defined at size 5000, but you're setting it to equal half of the original array's size already.  This will lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on its own.

Second, you need to ensure that you're only adding half of the elements to your other array.  The start position differs by virtue of your offset `i + halfLim`, but the final iteration must still come in at half of your max size.

So, you'd need to make two changes:

- `i` must start at 0, and
- the loop must terminate at `halfLim`.

The code to do that is as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < halfLim ; ++i) {
    b[i] = data[i+halfLim];
}
```

Also, be sure to write `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top, and use `Arrays.toString(a)` when you want to print `a`, or you'll just get an object string reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in your second for loop:

- you initialized `b` array with a size of half limit which is `5000`
- initial value of `i` is set to `halfLim(5000)`, this index simply doesn't exist because it too large
- `data[i + halfLim]` - when initial value of i set to `halfLim`, you're trying to access the element at `index 5000 + 5000`, this is also out of bound of data array

Answer (score 0):

`b[i]` is actually `b[5000]` which is out of bound.Try this:

```
   double[] b = new double[halfLim];
   for(int i = 0 ; i < (lim/2) ; i++) {//i should be 0 to start inserting data at index zero
       b[i] = data[halfLim];//Start collecting data from where you stopped
       halfLim++;//increment halfLim to pick next data
   }

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own loops, you should use the Java Library, in particular the [`Arrays.copyOfRange(double[] original, int from, int to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-double:A-int-int-) method.

*Example*

```
double[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int half = (data.length + 1) / 2; // Make first half larger if odd sized
double[] a = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 0, half);
double[] b = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, half, data.length);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

*Output*

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```